# How to get notified when SQL Replication finishes work

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, database-replication

In my case, I am creating records in SQL Server database. There is a running replication on the database.

Before returning results to client, I need to query the data in the replicated database.

For now, I am using a timer, whereby every 2 seconds I query data from replicated database to see if the data has been replicated.

Is there a way to find out when the data has been replicated before returning results to client and without using Timer?

Technologies used: ASP.NET MVC/JavaScript & backend is SQL Server.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're hoping for.  Replication is a constant occurrence, it doesn't really "finish".  If you have a large database, with lots of data changes going on, do you really want to be notified every time sub is equal to pub?  Is it that important for the "freshest" of data? then you probably shouldn't be querying from the replicate IMO.

Comment: short answer: NO! but it depends a lot of what do you want (it's not veru clear). Dependending on your needs you can use a trigger in the target table of the replicated DB. In general the values ill be replicated as it is commited on source DB. Also you can just check if there are problems with the replication and assume if theres not in error log it's ok

Comment: In short, the replciations is always running, it don't "finishes"

Comment: What is your purpose for notifying the user that the data has been replicated? You're very likely creating a lot of overhead at your subscriber in trying to determine whether data has or has not been delivered to it.

Comment: Idea is when I submit a batch to the database to get created with IDs, etc. I want to retrieve those submitted records from the replication database. So what I meant by "finishes" is replicating the batch I sent to store in the original database. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. [You can Configure Predefined Replication Alerts (SQL Server Management Studio)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152496.aspx).

> SQL Server Management Studio and Microsoft SQL Server Agent provide a way to monitor events, such as replication agent events, using alerts. SQL Server Agent monitors the Windows application log for events that are associated with alerts. If such an event occurs, SQL Server Agent responds automatically, by executing a task that you have defined and/or sending e-mail or a pager message to a specified operator. SQL Server includes a set of predefined alerts for replication agents that you can configure to execute a task and/or notify an operator.

Refer to these links: [Use Alerts for Replication Agent Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151752.aspx), [View Information and Perform Tasks for a Subscription (Replication Monitor)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151332.aspx).

There is also a [Microsoft SQL Server Replication Monitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151780.aspx), which is a graphical tool that allows you to monitor the overall health of a replication topology.

Comment: I'm not sure that any of the alerts pointed out in the linked articles would meet the criteria that OP is looking for.